# View count for a video embedded on SharePoint page

Tags: 2013, statistics, analytics

I have a page created on a SharePoint site, on which a video has been embedded.
I have full control over that site collection only. No access to Central Admin.

Is there a way where I can know, how many users have viewed that video? (with their names, if possible)

I ran a Audit Log Report from Site Settings.
But the page where the video is embedded doesn't come up in the result.

Any advise?

Thanks

Comment: Google analytics?

Comment: cannot implement that.... but still.. it will show future data.
I will need data on how many users have already seen the video.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to create a Custom List and make every pageview create a new Item in that list.

- The Title gets the pagename (serverRequestPath)
- The Created/Created By info is automatically assigned

**Obfuscation (because you are playing Big Brother)**

Users need create rights on the List, you could also

- limit access so they can only read their own entries
- Make the default View an empty view

**Recording each pageview**

*I usually do not promote jQuery, but in this case jQuery ajax solves a whole load of potential browser issues*

```
    /*global document,window,navigator,console*/
    /*global SP,$,_spPageContextInfo*/
    /*jshint -W030*/ //allow expression assignments
    SP.SOD.registerSod('CDNJQ', "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js");
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('CDNJQ', null, function () {
        try { //extra try catch to not hold on CORS errors
            var trackError = function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console && console.log('trackPage', textStatus, errorThrown);
            };
            var trackSite = '/.', //default root SiteCollection
                trackList = 'NAME_OF_YOUR_TRACKING_LIST';
            var item = {
                '__metadata': {
                    'type': 'SP.List'
                },
                'Title': _spPageContextInfo.serverRequestPath
            };
            $.ajax({
                url: trackSite + "/_api/contextinfo",
                type: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
                },
                success: function (contextData) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: trackSite + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + trackList + "')/items?@target='" + trackSite + "'",
                        method: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
                        data: JSON.stringify(item),
                        async: true,
                        headers: {
                            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            console && console.log('trackPage success');
                        },
                        error: trackError
                    });
                },
                error: trackError
            });
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
        }
    });
```

Notes

- Link from a CEWP or JSlink or put into SEWP or MasterPage
- Nested Ajax call is a remnant from some more complex implementation

iJS JX